# bootstrap navbar in single page app

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with Bootstrap's navbar: https://jsfiddle.net/2wwgt3to/1/ 
I'm making single page application and it turns out that bootstraps dropdown navigation menu for mobile is not really working well with it i.e. its not collapsing after clicking, I managed to solve this with adding `data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar"` attributes but then the whole menu is collapsing even when it is not in dropdown form.

Comment: I don't understand. Everything looks ok on your example?

Comment: When you click on "Home" "about" etc. navbar is doing "collapse animation" (http://i.imgur.com/BrRAedY.gifv) which I want to get rid of for desktop view, it's acting fine when navbar is in mobile mode (hamburger dropdown)

Answer (score 0):

Remove data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" from

```
<div data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
```

Edited code:

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
    </div>
    <div  id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="../navbar/">Default</a></li>
        <li><a href="../navbar-static-top/">Static top</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="./">Fixed top <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Yeah, but I need this so the dropdown will roll up after clicking an option from menu like this http://i.imgur.com/pgqN9PI.gifv

Comment: It does that now. Look on fiddle, I'm clicking on About and collapsible menu closes

Comment: I copy-pasted your code and unfortunately it doesn't work for me https://jsfiddle.net/2wwgt3to/6/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/elance/2wwgt3to/10/   move the screen to see it is working, but press refresh (ctrl + f5) before checking on different sizes. Now it is set to work on small devices, navbar collapse + closing collapsible menu on click. On big screen everything stays untouched

Comment: Great! Thanks for help!